# Groupchat SASL authentication failed using mechanism PLAIN

Tags: android

```
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:341)

at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:204)

at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:357)
```

// This is my code...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.Form;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.FormField;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.DiscussionHistory;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.quickblox.module.chat.QBChat;



public class GroupChatController {

    // ================= QuickBlox ===== Step 8 =================
    // Get QuickBlox chat server domain.
    // There will be created connection with chat server below.
    public static final String CHAT_SERVER = QBChat.getChatServerDomain();

    private XMPPConnection connection;

    private ConnectionConfiguration config;
    private Chat groupChat;

    private String chatLogin;
    private String password;
    private String groupName;

    private String passgroupName;

    Context context;



    private String quickusername;

    private ChatManager chatManager;

  //  private boolean isGroupchat;

    MultiUserChat muc;

    public GroupChatController(String chatLogin, String password) {

        this.chatLogin = chatLogin;

        this.password = password;
    }
```

//Here My Groupchat  start

```
    public void startChat(final String groupName) {

        this.groupName = groupName;


       // this.isGroupchat = isGroup;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Chat action 1 -- create connection.

                Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

                config = new ConnectionConfiguration(CHAT_SERVER);

                connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

                try 
                {

                //Here is showing error connections

                    connection.connect();

                    connection.login(chatLogin, password);

                        //boolean supports = MultiUserChat.isServiceEnabled(connection, chatLogin+"@muc.chat.quickblox.com");

                           // Example 416_sedin@muc.chat.quickblox.com

                            muc = new MultiUserChat(connection,groupName+"@muc.chat.quickblox.com");

                            DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();

                            history.setMaxStanzas(3);

                            muc.join(chatLogin, password, history, SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());

                            muc.addMessageListener(groupchatManagerListener);                           


                } catch (XMPPException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }/*catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }*/
                }



        }).start();
    }
```

//Create Mygroup

```
 public void createGroupChat(final String groupName,final String qucikusername) {

        this.passgroupName = groupName;

        this.quickusername=qucikusername;

       // this.isGroupchat = isGroup;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Chat action 1 -- create connection.

                Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

                config = new ConnectionConfiguration(CHAT_SERVER);

                connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

                try 

                {

                    //SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

                    connection.connect();

                    connection.login(chatLogin, password);

                            MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection,"groupid_"+groupName+"@muc.chat.quickblox.com");

                           // int appid= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.QuickBoxid);

                           // Log.i("TAG QUICKID", "QUICKBOX ID CHECK direct"+appid);

                            muc.create(qucikusername);

                            //muc.create(appid+"_"+groupName);

                           // muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));       


                } catch (XMPPException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


//Listner for groupchat   

    private PacketListener groupchatManagerListener = new PacketListener() {


        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

            if (onMessageReceivedListener != null) {

                onMessageReceivedListener.onGroupMessageReceived(packet);
            }    

        }
    };
```

//Here sending group messages

```
    public void sendGroupMessage(String message) {

        try {

            if(muc!=null)
            {               
                muc.sendMessage(message);
            }

        }catch(XMPPException xmppe) {

            xmppe.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

   /* public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {onMessageReceivedListener
            if (chat != null) {
                chat.sendMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/

   /* private MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            // 'from' and 'to' fields contains senders ids, e.g.
            // 17792-1028@chat.quickblox.com/mac-167
            // 17744-1028@chat.quickblox.com/Smack
            String from = message.getFrom().split("@")[0];
            String to = message.getTo().split("@")[0];



            System.out.println(String.format(">>> Message received (from=%s, to=%s): %s",
                    from, to, message.getBody()));

            if (onMessageReceivedListener != null) {
                onMessageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
    };*/

    public static interface OnGroupMessageReceivedListener {
        void onGroupMessageReceived(Packet packet);
    }    

    private OnGroupMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener;

    public OnGroupMessageReceivedListener getOnMessageReceivedListener() {

        return onMessageReceivedListener;

    }

    public void setOnMessageReceivedListener(OnGroupMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener) {

        this.onMessageReceivedListener = onMessageReceivedListener;

    }

    // Callback that performs when device retrieves incoming message.
  /*  private OnMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener;

    public OnMessageReceivedListener getOnMessageReceivedListener() {
        return onMessageReceivedListener;
    }

    public void setOnMessageReceivedListener(OnMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener) {
        this.onMessageReceivedListener = onMessageReceivedListener;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: can you pls share your code where you are strucking..

Comment: thanks to reply to ramkiran

Answer (score 0):

After having successful connection, check that user is authenticated (means logging or not).
So use this

```
connection.isAuthenticated();
```

before configuring MUC...