# How to perform GroupChat in android using XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp

I am working on group chat in android using asmack library. I am able to chat with single user  but getting problems in group chat.
I require any tutorial or code to perform group chat.

I've referenced [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112653/groupchat-sasl-authentication-failed-using-mechanism-plain) and [this blog post](http://androidbydavid.blogspot.in/2013/07/multiuserchat-with-xmpp-android-tutorial.html) when looking for a solution.

Comment: U got any solution???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void MUC_Configure(String roomname){

    try{
        muc = new MultiUserChat(XMPPSmackConnection.connection, roomname+Constant._hostNameWithCONF);
        muc.create("nickname1");

        // Send an empty room configuration form which indicates that we want an instant room
        muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));

        muc.join("nickname1");
        muc.invite("column1"+Constant._hostNameWithAt+"/Smack", "Meet me in this excellent room");
        muc.addInvitationRejectionListener(this);
        muc.addMessageListener(this);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Finally I done with the above method.

Comment: I am using same code, for roomname-"samck" and Constant._hostNameWithAt- "uc.dev.8x8.com". I am getting exception at  muc.create("nickname1");. As org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:177)
org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:352)
org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.createOrJoin(MultiUserChat.java:419)org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:393)
at com.example.xmppapp.GroupChat.getConnection(GroupChat.java:31)

Comment: can you give some hint for COntact??

Comment: use this   roomname@conference.jabber.org

Comment: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html

Comment: @ROHITPARMAR .jabber.org is complersay bcz i m connection view 54.168.198.54:5222 via ip

Comment: is conference keyword is mandatory or we can have any other subdomain name. Just curious to know.